# Datetime format read from Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a little funny problem that I would like to share with you and am thankfully expecting from you some replies because I don't have an answer myself.
I have a DataGridView (dgv) in which one column is saved for datetime display. 
I initialize it like a date string often used in MySQL, i.e 2011/1/3 in the dgv construction, and sure enough it displays correctly as a human readable string, that is 1/3/2011. I then save all the displayed content into another excel file.
After that I try to reopen it, here is the code after pressing the Open button

```
private void OpenClicked(object sender, ....)
{
   dataGV.Rows.Clear(); 
   OpenAndBindXls(filename,dataGV);  
}
```

Sadly, the datetime display is not as expected, it is all 5762,3552,3354 etc. 
I have two real questions,
[1] How can I explain the above problem ?
[2] In the above code, it only deletes rows, what methods should I use if I would like to delete even the columns but still keep the instance alive?

[Edit] Sorry the second question was made when my mind wasn't fresh at all, I noticed my stupidity. I correct it by just add `dataGV.Columns.Clear();` :-D. How stupid! Well I am tired, I will take some sleep to refresh my mind now. Thanks anyway for reading.

Comment: You question does not show what is in your OpenAndBindXLS method, nor does it show what the DataGridViewCell contains. Do you read Value or Value2 from the Excel cell? If it's Value2, you won't get date strings, but datetime values which you must convert and format in the Grid, for example in the CellFormatting event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are getting the date time format in ticks and not as you expect.
You can try either converting the data before binding or use the CellFormatting event to convert the value to a visual datetime:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx